# como hacer un buscador en laravel con tablas relacionadas

Tags: php, laravel, buscador, scope

hola buenos días comunidad hoy quisiera preguntarles como hacer para realizar un scope en laravel pero que este se relacione con otras tablas, aquí en el ejemplo estoy buscando directamente solo el id del instalador y necesito buscarlo a través del nombre pero cuando intento relacionarlo por getinstalador me da error algún consejo que me puedan dar? se les agradecería

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Instalador_punto extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = ['punto_id','instalador_id','cant_dia','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin'];

public function getinstalador()
  {

return $this->belongsTo(Instalador::class, 'instalador_id');

}

public function getpunto()
  {
  return $this->belongsTo(Punto::class, 'punto_id');

}
  public function scopeSearch($query, $instalador_id)
    {
      return $query->where('instalador_id', 'LIKE', "%$instalador_id%");

```
}
//
```

}

```
public function instaladoresindex(Punto $punto, Request $request)
{

    $instaladores = Instalador_punto::Search($request->instalador_id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);




       return view('/puntos/instaladores/instaladoresindex')->with(compact('instaladores','punto'));
    //
}
```

id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
      
        
          Buscar

Comment: Anexa los códigos en forma de texto, para que sea más fácil reproducirlo y así poder orientarte mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Inténtalo de esta manera:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $instalador_id){
    $query->whereHas("getinstalador", function ($query) use ($instalador_id) {
        $query->where('id', $instalador_id);
    });
}
```

Ya que tienes hechas las relaciones entre los modelos, puedes usar eloquent para armar tus queries, en este caso usando la funcion [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Espero que te funcione, deberia funcionar.

Comment: lo intente asi como lo pusiste pero no funciono porque de por si no me trae los instaladores a la vista ni los busca tampoco

Comment: si haces un dd() cuando ejecutas las funcion, que te muestra?